# Can I shell into a worker dyno on Heroku?

Tags: docker, heroku, heroku-cli

I can shell into a Heroku app using the CLI command:

```
heroku run -a app-name bash
```

This works beautifully, however, I cannot seem to be able to specify which dyno I want to shell into. I have one `web` and one `worker` dyno, each with their own Docker image, and the run command always goes into the web.

Is there a solution to shell into a worker dyno?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself. Based on [Docker's documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#one-off-dynos):

> If your app is composed of multiple Docker images, you can target the process type when creating a one-off dyno:

```
$ heroku run bash --type=worker
```

This works exactly as expected.